# How do I reverse a C++ vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std

Is there a built-in vector function in C++ to reverse a vector in place?

Or do you just have to do it manually?

Answer (score 374, accepted):

There's a function `std::reverse` in the `algorithm` header for this purpose.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> a;
  std::reverse(a.begin(), a.end());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how to reverse vector of vectors? I want v[0] to be swapped with v[v.size()-1] and the order of v[0][i] element remain as it is. This is similar to changing order of rows (if a vector is viewed as a Matrix). If a vector is defined as: vector<vector<int> > v; reverse(v.begin(), v.end()) doesn't reverse it. TIA!

Comment: @VikasGoel in fact the snippet you suggest should work.  Maybe there is some other problem?

Comment: you can also keep the elements in reverse order, but then iterate backwards:

for(auto i=a.end(); i!=a.begin();i--) {...} 

although that can be tricky due to off-by-one errors. so using rbegin() and rend() like others suggest is better

Answer (score 56):

All containers offer a reversed *view* of their content with `rbegin()` and `rend()`. These two functions return so-calles *reverse iterators*, which can be used like normal ones, but it will look like the container is actually reversed.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class InIt>
void print_range(InIt first, InIt last, char const* delim = "\n"){
  --last;
  for(; first != last; ++first){
    std::cout << *first << delim;
  }
  std::cout << *first;
}

int main(){
  int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  std::vector<int> v(a, a+5);
  print_range(v.begin(), v.end(), "->");
  std::cout << "\n=============\n";
  print_range(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), "<-");
}
```

[Live example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/tJ672). Output:

```
1->2->3->4->5
=============
5<-4<-3<-2<-1
```

Comment: that doesn't however reverse the vector in-place. You could create a new vector with std::vector<T> v2( v1.rbegin(), v1.rend() ); v2.swap(v1); which would effectively use your solution. I don't see how it is more elegant or advantageous in any way to using std::reverse though.

Comment: @CashCow: Well, for one, it's a no-op, it's O(1). Reversing.. not so much. Most of the time, you don't really need a reversed container, you only need to *see* it as reversed. In fact, I can't think of a situation where you actually need a reversed container that can't be solved with reverse iterators.

Comment: @CashCow: Elegance is not always true elegance. In most cases in my professional career, I just needed a reversed view, but not a reversed vector. And in all those cases, performance would suffer totally needlessy if you'd create more copies or transform the ordering. Would you also `std::sort` a 1000 element vector, if you just need the top-10 in unspecified order, because it is more elegant than `std::partition`? This is the school of thought that cripples my PC experience today as it did 15 years ago, with the difference that yet more cycles are wasted, billions of them.

Comment: `print_range` is not correct: it will not work when *empty* range is passed.

Comment: so the big question is, what will `std::reverse(a.rbegin(), a.rend())` do?  ;^)

Comment: nitpick: `std::forward_list` is a container that doesn't have `rbegin rend`

Comment: @Orwellophile the same as `std::reverse(a.begin(), a.end())` but with the arguments to `swap` (via `iter_swap`) effectively switched

Comment: @caleth either sounds suspiciously like two `std::reverse`s make a `std::forward`.  **the scary thing:** that might even compile and function correctly.

Comment: @Orwellophile No, I mean that instead of `swap(first_element, last_element)` etc it's `swap(last_element, first_element)`

Comment: @Xeo an example where you actually need to compute the reversed vector is when you use an API whose implementation you cannot change.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `std::reverse` like this

```
std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Answer (score 5):

Often the reason you want to reverse the vector is because you fill it by pushing all the items on at the end but were actually receiving them in reverse order. In that case you can reverse the container as you go by using a `deque` instead and pushing them directly on the front. (Or you could insert the items at the front with `vector::insert()` instead, but that would be slow when there are lots of items because it has to shuffle all the other items along for every insertion.) So as opposed to:

```
std::vector<int> foo;
int nextItem;
while (getNext(nextItem)) {
    foo.push_back(nextItem);
}
std::reverse(foo.begin(), foo.end());
```

You can instead do:

```
std::deque<int> foo;
int nextItem;
while (getNext(nextItem)) {
    foo.push_front(nextItem);
}
// No reverse needed - already in correct order
```

Comment: the downside is that the elements are no longer contiguous in memory like a vector, so you can't use .data()

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `std::list` instead of `std::vector`. `list` has a built-in function [list::reverse](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/reverse/) for reversing elements.

Comment: std::list should be preferred over vector in the only specific case of inserting many elements into arbitrary positions in the sequence. Using std::list over vector just because you will reverse the sequence is a bad idea performance-wise.